# Perl and parameterised statements

Tags: perl, sql-injection

i'm looking for confirmation that parameterised statements are not being executed correctly. Current code is as follows:

```
$ywant = "user supplied integer";
$select = "SELECT a.Authors, a.PublicationYear, a.Title, a.URL, a.ArticleID, f.Format ".
          "FROM   tbl_ETI_Article a, tbl_ETI_Format f  ".
          "WHERE  a.PublicationYear = '".$ywant."' ".
          "AND a.FID = f.FID ".
          "ORDER BY a.PublicationYear DESC, a.Title ASC";

$sth = $dbh->prepare( " $select " );
$sth->execute();
```

i understand that the $ywant variable in the select string should be replaced with a placeholder '?' and then the user supplied data be placed as an argument in the execute statement.

My question is does the above still offer any protection against injection attacks as it is still "being prepared"?

Comment: If this is production code, then there are a couple more issues apart from the SQL injection risk. I would think it has no `use strict`, because the variables aren't lexically declared with `my`. And there's no need to put quotes around `$select` when you pass it to `prepare`. If I got this code in a code review I would not pass it through.

Comment: All statements have to be prepared, whether you call the method explicitly or not. Calling it explicitly offers no protection whatsoever

Answer (score 5):

That is a risky SQL, because of $ywant may have malicious code if you can't trust its source. So it is much better to do this:

```
$ywant = "user supplied integer";
$select = qq{SELECT a.Authors, a.PublicationYear, a.Title, a.URL, a.ArticleID, f.Format
FROM   tbl_ETI_Article a, tbl_ETI_Format f
WHERE  a.PublicationYear = ?
AND a.FID = f.FID
ORDER BY a.PublicationYear DESC, a.Title ASC};

$sth = $dbh->prepare($select);
$sth->execute($ywant);
```

And avoid any SQL Injection potential problem. The prepare statement doesn't protect you by itself for this kind of attack

Comment: yes thank you very much, i will be changing the offending code to follow your example

Comment: Alternatively, `$ywant` contains a valid year. But it's so much easier and safe to simply use parameters.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is does the above still offer any protection against injection attacks as it is still "being prepared"?

No.

Using parameters protects against SQL injection.  Prepared statements do not (except insofar as they enable the use of parameters) .

Comment: yes thank you, i just wanted to get confirmation as i didn't think it was doing any protecting as it is. it's a pretty easy fix. Thanks